# sqlite between operator does not return rows in db

Tags: sql, sqlite

When I use this query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM verdicts WHERE Age BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

I get 17 rows. But when I use this query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM verdicts WHERE Age BETWEEN 7 AND 20
```

I get 0 rows. I know there are additional rows that should be caught by the second query. And the second query should be catching all the rows the first query catches. Does anyone know what could be happening?

The age column contains almost all ints except a couple text values such as:

0-10, 10-20, etc.

Could this be my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect `Age` is stored as a string.  That is a bad, bad thing.  So, your comparison is really:

```
where Age between '7' and '20'
```

Because '7' is greater than '20', `between` returns nothing (the smaller value goes first).

Basically, there is not that much you can do with your data.  You should really fix the data format.  Here are possibilities:

- Store `Age` as a number.
- Have numeric columns for MinAge and MaxAge if you are dealing with ranges.
- If you must use strings, then zero pad them so they are the same length:  `'007'` instead of `'7'`.

If you do the last, then this will work:

```
where Age between '007' and '028'
```